# Inside subprocess.run(..., check=True), how to prevent a failed command from exiting with a non-zero status?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, subprocess

I'd like the following piece of code to pass:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run("pkill -f non_existent_process_name || true", shell=True, check=True)
```

However, it always errors:

> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pkill -f non_existent_process_name || true' died with <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>.

Why is that?  How can I make this work?

In a normal terminal shell, running `(pkill -f non_existent_process_name || true); echo $?` shows 0, which means the part in parenthesis exits with 0, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting the `SIGTERM` is because you're inadvertently killing the shell that's running `pkill`.

When you run a command with `shell=True` it runs the command as the argument to a shell, something like this:

```
/bin/sh -c 'pkill -f non_existent_process_name || true'
```

Since `non_existent_process_name` is part of the command line for `/bin/sh`, the shell is killed.

Based on exactly what process you're trying to match, you'll need to experiment with options to `pkill`. Either remove `-f` or adding `-x` might work.